# SQL Server : IF Condition in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a bit parameter

```
@IsInRetry
```

If it is false I have to set the where condition to

```
attempts = 0
```

else if it is true I have to set the where condition to

```
attempts > 0
```

How could this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way:

```
( (@IsInRetry = 0 and attempts = 0) or (@IsInRetry = 1 and attempts > 0) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WHERE (attempts = @IsInRetry or (@IsInRetry = 1 and attempts > 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, should work also for negative attempts :-)

`@IsInRetry = (attempts > 0)`

Greetings.

Answer (score -1):

This:

```
if @IsInRetry = 0x0
   BEGIN    
      SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl 
      WHERE attempts = 0
   END
ELSE    
   BEGIN 
      SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl 
      WHERE attempts = 1
   END
```

Comment: I need to specify the condition in the Where as I have quite a long query that is not feasible to duplicate.